# Failed to Upgrade pip due to pip path error

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I checked my pip path as follow:

```
!pip -V
```

```
 pip 22.0.3 from C:\Users\ymx19\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

then I have updated pip in Command Prompt as

```
-m pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
 WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ymx19\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

the updated happened in python39 rather than python38. How can I change the path to python38 or make python39 become the new default path?

Comment: This question is related to updating the path environmental variable in windows. See here https://windowsreport.com/edit-windows-path-environment-variable/ or google how to edit path environment windows

Comment: Type `env` in the search box -> click on edit environment variables -> find the environment variable named `PATH` -> add the path shown in error. that's it